# Unable to get the returned value while calling Stored Procedure from JPA

Tags: sql-server, jpa, stored-procedures, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

The SP looks like:-

```
CREATE PROCEDURE <spnamegoeshere>
AS
BEGIN
/*  Some code goes here */
return 102323   /*Need to get this value*/
END
GO
```

We are executing a Stored Procedure (hosted in SQL SERVER), through JPA using

```
createStoredProcedureQuery("spnamegoeshere");
```

I need to get that returned value "**102323**". Unfortunatly, using above command, unable to get.

After searching a bit, got this link.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/using-a-stored-procedure-with-a-return-status?view=sql-server-2017

As per the above doc, I can able to get the value, if I use .

```
CallableStatement
```

Any way to do the same using the JPA, **without modifying the SP**?

Could someone share some input here.

Comment: Don't use `RETURN`. Use an `OUTPUT` parameter.

Comment: @Larnu: Hi, Thx for the reply. Yes. But I should not modify the SP because of constraints. Any way to achieve without it?

Comment: Here's an idea ... present your code about HOW you are using and invoking `StoredProcedureQuery`. Docs for it explain very clearly how to get return values. http://www.datanucleus.org:15080/products/accessplatform_5_2/jpa/query.html#_simple_execution_returning_output_parameters

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
  @Test
  public void testProc() {
    SimpleJdbcCall call = new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate);
    Map<String, Object> map = call.withProcedureName("retValTestProc").withReturnValue().execute();
    Assert.assertNotNull("Expected not null result but it is", Objects.nonNull(map));
    Assert.assertTrue("Expected size = 1, actual=" + map.size(), map.size() == 1);
    Assert.assertTrue("Expected value=102323, actual=" + map.get("RETURN_VALUE"),
                      Objects.equals(102323, map.get("RETURN_VALUE")));
  }
```

Where `retValTestProc = <spnamegoeshere>`

Also you can create a `SimpleJdbcCall` with a `DataSource` constructor

Comment: Hi @yuriy: any methods from entitymanager (jpa) instead of jdbc comands. In question to I suggested the same. Any idea? Thx